# Azure App Service - instance count

Tags: azure, cloud, azure-app-service-plans

We'd like to add instances to our Azure App Service plan to scale out. Everything we've got is stateless, apart from one app. Because of the way that app is used, if there is more than one instance of it things will quickly go crazy. We can work fix this eventually - we need to build in shared storage for its state - but at the moment we don't have enough the time.

Is there any way to scale out an app service plan, but indicate that particular apps should only ever be run on one host?

Comment: I don't think this is possible. But why not just create a different App Service for that app and when you implement the changes you can switch it back.

Comment: I didn't consider this initially, as I figured it would be a huge ordeal to recreate the web app in the new app service. But it is a 2 click operation to move! Ended up going this way, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming this isn't possible, however it turns out to be surprisingly easy to move an existing app between app service plans without having to recreate the configuration. I have gone down this route for now with an eye to fixing the clustering issue and moving the app back into the original app service plan later.

Answer (score 0):

Did you think about using Cloud Services or Service Fabric? Cloud Services role model is what you are thinking of - you are able to scale only one component of the solution.